# Webcam not working on Ubuntu 22.04 Macbook pro 2018 Intel chip

Tags: drivers, 22.04, webcam, macbook-pro

I tried all the ideas here: https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/wiki/Installation#get-started-on-ubuntu

And still no webcam on my macbook.

dmesg | grep facetime

```
[    2.006856] facetimehd: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.006859] facetimehd: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Relevant information when I try to install might be:

```
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic'
Generate modules.dep and map files
Adding kernel modules
modprobe: FATAL: Module bdc_pci not found.
```

I tried adding `depmod -A` after install, but that doesn't seem to change anything..

lsusb gives me the impression the hardware isn't even found:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:0265 Apple, Inc. Magic Trackpad
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0255 Apple, Inc. USB KEYBOARD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @chili555 do you have an idea for this one as well perhaps?